# Where do I add the html to the MaterializeCSS tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have set html attribute to 'true' in the jquery. But where exactly do I place the html code?

jQuery

```
$('.test-tooltip').tooltip({
            delay: 50,
            html: true,

        });
```

HTML

```
<a class="test-tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am tooltip">
```

Answer (score 1):

You place the HTML code in the `data-tooltip` attribute:

```
<a class="test-tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I <b>am</b> tooltip">
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/34yyog5o/)**

Comment: Is it possible to embed videos in the data-tooltip?
I attempted to add the embed code but got some errors.

Comment: That's really what your question should be titled and talk about. As my answer demonstrates, obviously you can add HTML to a tooltip. However whether you can embed a video is unclear. If you tried, what happened?

Comment: My mistake I'll try to be more specific in the future. 

It looks like since the iframe has quotes inside it there are issues stemming from that. I think the solution is to escape the quotes but I'm not exactly sure how. Its not allowing for tags to close.

Here is the iframe code:

<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Q8TXgCzxEnw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes on the attribute and single quotes on the content (or vice-versa)? E.g. `data-tooltip='<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Q8TXgCzxEnw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'`

Comment: I did try that and it actually displays the html code instead of running it . I even tried escaping the quotes with the &quot  but that had the same effect.

Comment: Ok so I used your code in the tooltip attribute in the jquery and something did pop up. The iframe doesn't take up the full width its just a tiny black box but I think I can try and work through what's going on.

Comment: From what I read, materializecss just uses jQuery's `.htm()` to render the tooltip's HTML, so it should accept any valid HTML. In other words, it doesn't appear as if only a specific few elements are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in `data-tooltip`.

```
<a class="test-tooltip" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="<p>I am tooltip</p>">Hello!</a>
```

Comment: I'm attempting to add embedded youtube code into the data-tooltip but the quotes inside the iframe are causing issues. Do you know whether I need to escape quotes inside the html?